# Issue about transfer sheet through xlrd or openpyxl to xlsxwriter

Tags: excel, openpyxl, xlrd, xlsxwriter

Now i'm using xlsxwriter to read data from csv files and making charts as information. but now i want to add another worksheet from another xlsx file. Which module can i use to copy it, xlrd or openpyxl?

i have do some several testing like:

```
 workbook_template = openpyxl.load_workbook('Test_template.xlsx')
 cover_template = workbook_template.get_sheet_by_name('Cover')
 worksheet_cover = Report.add_worksheet("Cover")
 worksheet_cover = cover_template
```

but it didn't work, can anyone teach me how to make it work? thanks

Comment: What **doesn't work**?

Comment: worksheet_cover have been create , but it all blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an example below that uses xlsxwriter to create a worksheet with a chart, and then using openpyxl reads in this existing workbook and adds a new worksheet.

I'm using the latest version of openpyxl downloaded from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl).  If you're using an older version you may loose your chart based on what I've been reading [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/523/charts-in-existing-worksheets-lost).

```
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#modified example from xlsxwriter documentation at http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html
data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
    [3, 6, 9, 12, 15],
]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test_template.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

worksheet.write_column('A1', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B1', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C1', data[2])

chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5'})

worksheet.insert_chart('A10', chart)

workbook.close()

#opening xlsxwriter created workbook with openpyxl and adding a sheet

workbook = load_workbook('Test_template.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.create_sheet('new_sheet')
worksheet["A1"] = "Putting some text in"
workbook.save('Test_template.xlsx')
```

Comment: First , thanks for your example.
I've design all the item and placement of data through xlsxwriter.
But now i only want to add a single sheet with template. Thus i need to import with xlrd. Or do you have another option for importing existed file? thanks !

Comment: By the way, how to install new version of openpyxl with tar.gz file
1. i have used openpyxl for 2.4.9 but no chart show up
2. i uninstall 2.4.9 version and reinstall 2.5.0b1 but i shows the error:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

Comment: finally i use the [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6tmmvo/cant_upgrade_openpyxl/) to solve the upgrade openpyxl

Comment: You should be able to add a sheet to an existing file using openpyxl.  The last four lines in my answer are opening the existing file and adding a sheet.  Hopefully that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @patrickjlong1 Is there a way to create sheet in xlsxwriter and add that sheet to existing excel file using openpyxl ?